# Populating a hidden form value based on user form entry without leaving the page

Tags: javascript

A bit stuck here all... basically, I have a PHP script that  calls a REST service, interprets the result.  We've decided I want to call said service without refreshing the page, to populate the form without the need for refresh.  As such, I've attempted to do what I need in Javascript.  The below is initial attempts, which, keep in mind, makes the page stop loading currently with no errors rendered in Firefox console.  I'd love any hints or pushes in the right direction!

1. List item

   ```
       var url = "http://urltoquery"; 

       function getleademail() { 

       var idValue = document.getElementById("sublabel_postal").value; 

       http.open("GET", url + escape(idValue), true); 

       http.onreadystatechange = handleHttpResponse; 

       http.send(null); }



       function handleHttpResponse() { 

       var results = http.responseText; 

                         }
   ```

Comment: Firstly we assume http is a XMLHttpRequest or ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP") object.  Secondly is the restful webservice on the same domain as the page ?  ALso is there a specific question you are asking here ?

Comment: Hi!  Thanks for the response.  It is an XMLHttpRequest.  The service is on a different domain then the page.   My question is specifically some directive to get it to work.  Currently, said script stops the page from further loading.  (Script placed immediately after sublabel_postal form input field)

Comment: ok - if the restful service is a different domain then you will not be able to use it via ajax, it has to be the same domain. The way round this would be to create a proxy at your php layer. When you manipulate the DOM if it is an inline script then the page only has in the dom where it has got up to. Question - What is it that starts the function getleademail, and when is this done? We could do with a bit more of the page html tbh rather than just a snippet.

Comment: Thanks again Symeon.  It's onkeyup to call the function.  The intent here is that once the user enters their zip/postal code, the function is triggered.

Comment: So the problem is the page stops loading at at the script?  in which case we need to see the page html. Or is it the script just does not run?  Have you stepped through it in debug that would say at what point it errors, or look in the javascript console to see any errors, or in the network activity to see any errors, - as said before if the web service is on a different domain it will error as this is not allowed in ajax.